# Exibir objetos dentro de uma table com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como adicionar um objeto em uma table, no exemplo abaixo o item possui um array com 2 objetos.
Como informar esses dois objetos dentro da tabela?

```js
let myjson ={
       "pedidoId": 1,
       "itens": [
          {
             "sku": "123",
             "nome": "produto 1",
             "quantidade": 1
          },
          {
             "sku": "1234",
             "nome": "produto 2",
             "quantidade": 2
          }
       ]
    }



let btn = document.querySelector("#search")
let list = document.querySelector("#list")

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
     console.log(myjson.itens.nome)
      let tb = document.createElement("tbody")
      
      tb.innerHTML = `<tr><th   scope="row">${myjson.pedidoId}</th>
<td>${myjson.itens.nome}</td>
<td>${myjson.itens.sku}</td>
<td>${myjson.itens.quantidade}</td>
</tr>`
      list.appendChild(tb);

 })
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <table class="table table-striped" id="list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">N° Pedido</th>
            <th scope="col">Item</th>
            <th scope="col">SKU</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantidade</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      
      </table>
      <div class="col-auto my-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="search">Procurar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="print" onclick="window.print();">imprimir</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como "itens" é um array, você precisa passar o **índice** do item que você quer que apareça.

Usando o **myjson** que você criou de exemplo, é necessário concatenar as strings de nome, sku e quantidade, para que todas as informações de todos os itens fiquem inteiros em uma linha. Para fazer isso vamos fazer um **for** para concatenar as strings.

Depois só adicionar as strings já concatenadas a **table**.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   let tb = document.createElement("tbody")
   
   // SKU
   var strSku = '<td>'
   for (item in myjson.itens) {
      strSku += `${myjson.itens[item].sku}, `
   }
   strSku = strSku.substr(0, strSku.length - 2)
   strSku += '</td>'

   // Nome
   var strNome = '<td>'
   for (item in myjson.itens) {
      strNome += `${myjson.itens[item].nome}, `
   }
   strNome = strNome.substr(0, strNome.length - 2)
   strNome += '</td>'

   // Quantidade
   var strQnt = '<td>'
   for (item in myjson.itens) {
      strQnt += `${myjson.itens[item].quantidade}, `
   }
   strQnt = strQnt.substr(0, strQnt.length - 2)
   strQnt += '</td>'

   tb.innerHTML += `<tr><th   scope="row">${myjson.pedidoId}</th>
      ${strNome}
      ${strSku}
      ${strQnt}
      </tr>`

   list.appendChild(tb);
})
```

O problema é que ao adicionar mais pedidos, esse código não vai funcionar. Pra resolver isso tomei a liberdade de mudar o seu **myjson** de exemplo e adicionar um pedido, ele ficou assim:

```
let myjson = {
   "pedidos": [
       {
           "pedidoId": 1,
           "itens": [
               {
                   "sku": "123",
                   "nome": "produto 1",
                   "quantidade": 1
               },
               {
                   "sku": "1234",
                   "nome": "produto 2",
                   "quantidade": 2
               }
           ]
       },
       {
          "pedidoId": 2,
          "itens": [
             {
                "sku": "321",
                "nome": "produto 3",
                "quantidade": 3
             },
             {
                "sku": "4321",
                "nome": "produto 4",
                "quantidade": 4
             }
          ]
       }
   ]
}
```

A diferença vai ser em percorrer o novo array de **pedidos**, mas a lógica mantém a mesma.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
   let tb = document.createElement("tbody")
   
   for (pedido in myjson.pedidos){

       // SKU
       var strSku = '<td>'
       for (item in myjson.pedidos[pedido].itens) {
           strSku += `${myjson.pedidos[pedido].itens[item].sku}, `
       }
       strSku = strSku.substr(0, strSku.length - 2)
       strSku += '</td>'
   
       // Nome
       var strNome = '<td>'
       for (item in myjson.pedidos[pedido].itens) {
           strNome += `${myjson.pedidos[pedido].itens[item].nome}, `
       }
       strNome = strNome.substr(0, strNome.length - 2)
       strNome += '</td>'
   
       // Quantidade
       var strQnt = '<td>'
       for (item in myjson.pedidos[pedido].itens) {
           strQnt += `${myjson.pedidos[pedido].itens[item].quantidade}, `
       }
       strQnt = strQnt.substr(0, strQnt.length - 2)
       strQnt += '</td>'
   
       tb.innerHTML += `<tr><th   scope="row">${myjson.pedidos[pedido].pedidoId}</th>
           ${strNome}
           ${strSku}
           ${strQnt}
           </tr>`
   
       list.appendChild(tb);
   }
})
```

Comment: Compreendi, mas nesse seu exemplo ele cria uma nova td e repete o id, gostaria de agrupar no mesmo item,  assim {pedido 1 -  sku1, sku2 - quantidade1, quantidade 2 }

aplicando a sua sugestão https://codepen.io/Aleixo/pen/poyNgzz

Comment: Editei a resposta, agora funciona o agrupamento dos pedidos

Comment: compreendi, cada for criar uma string com todos os itens agrupados, a unica alteração que fiz foi adicionar um </br> ao invés de usar ",". =) obrigado!